# How to keep messages from previous Thunderbird email account?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, smtp

I had an email account on first hosting server with its IMAP and SMTP. The server has been cracked and now I couldn't read emails from it.

I moved my doamin to another hosting server with another IMAP and SMTP. Now all my old messages kept on first-server, where I cann't access, and all new messages on the second-server. Also all my old messages kept in Thunderbid.

Now I change IMAP and SMTP server in Thunderbird and lost my old messages, but get new.

How to prevent old messages lost and get new messages in Thunderbird?

Comment: Unless you configured Thunderbird to actually download the emails, then you don't have a local copy of the emails, so there is nothing you can do to "keep" them since they are only contained on the server.

Comment: Now Thunderbird.contains old messages. I want to keep them, configure Thunderbird to new email settings to receive new messages, and want to add old messages to new ones. Merge them. Is it possible?

Comment: As I indicated unless you configured Thunderbird already to actually download the email, then its very likely, the emails ONLY exist on the server.

Comment: Lets try again. (1) Both Thunderbird and server (old server where I coudn't login) keep messages. I want to keep them. (2) Also I want to continue to get messages to the same email. That new messages will be stored in the new server and in Thunderbird. (3) If I configure T. to get messages from new server, old messages will be deleted. (I try, I know). (4) I don't want that T. will delete old messages. I want that T. will merge them with new. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. It is a little based on the answer of @George. +1

I install [add-ons for Thunderbird "ImportExportTool"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/). Select email folder with old messages and export it to the folder on a disk. Then I setup new email IMAP and SMTP servers for the same email address. Thunderbirder remove all old messages from those email folder and it stays clear. After that I create new folder in "Local Folders" part and import old messages in it.

As a result I have two folders with old messages and new ones. They are not merged, but I could use them both.

Another good extension that do the same without import/export is 
["Copy Folder" add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/copy-folder/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using IMAP, there is a future you can use that allows you to copy emails from one account into another.  Here is the [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer).  You can disregard ***Windows Easy Transfer*** as it wouldn't apply to you.  The second option ***Manually moving files*** will work for you.  You can also disregard the gmail setup portion as it doesn't apply to you as you already have an account to move to.


Another option is to export mail from Thunerburd itself in a form of the file.  Mozilla has a [knowledge base article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Importing_and_exporting_your_mail) about it.


Hope this helps!

Comment: If I export all messages from Thunderbird to file and then configure Thunderbird to get messages with new accouns settings (IMAP/SMPT), could I add, or apapend, or merge exported messages to new ones? Does Thunderbird keep imported messages? Or it will delete them because they are not on the new server?

Comment: @IvanZ Part 1 - I know for a fact if you export them, you'll have them saved in a file, so if they do get deleted you'll have a backup.  Now as far as importing them back into the Thunderbird, after you setup your new "old" email account, I am not sure what will happen, however, if it works (and I can't speak to a certainty, since I have never done what you want to do), I don't see why it wouldn't work the same way Outlook attaches archive .pst file(s) to the same account(s).

Comment: @IvanZ Part 2 - the way I see is you have a couple of options, one, export the messages, install Thunderbird on another computer and import them in, just to test it out and see that you got everything.  Other option, open a gmail account an copy those message there for a safe keeping, kind of like a place holder/temp storage and then copy them back after you hooked up your new servers for your email.

Comment: @IvanZ Part 3 - Or you can hook up your new service and import your exported file back in an see what happens (I don't like to give this advise, but if you don't want to go through other steps, you might hope it'll work like Outlook)